# How can I visually lay out a program before I start coding?

Tags: language-agnostic

I was wondering if there's anyway to layout what I want to code before I code it. Instead of drawing your ideas on a piece of paper, is there a program that lets you build a little demo or something before you start coding?

Comment: please edit your title to : 'prototyping techniques' or 'mockup tools'

Comment: but in my opinion, paper & pencil is the FAST and EASY way to design and refine UI :)

Comment: In this little thing we like to call "the industry", whiteboards enjoy some small popularity for the purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For mockups, I go with paper and pen or a [cheap whiteboard substitute](https://superuser.com/questions/17143/how-to-make-a-cheap-white-board/17144#17144), but [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) is an interesting tool for creating mockups. As it uses a deliberately handwritten style, you tend to focus more on the content than if the button should be 5 pixels to the left.

Here's an example:
[image: mockup image]
<sub>(source: [balsamiq.com](http://www.balsamiq.com/images/myTunez.gif))</sub>

Comment: if you use a whiteboard how do you show some of your employees who live far away?

Comment: with a digital camera and the ether

Comment: any idea of a free online alternative to Balsamiq?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Visio is good for this kind of thing.

Comment: Visio is the tool included my Microsoft, but it is not really a good tool for programmers to use.  There are much better visualization tools for the UI, and much better UML tools for design.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually known as making mock-ups. There have been several questions that may be of help:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295589/what-program-should-i-use-to-mock-up-guis
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606/what-software-can-i-use-to-create-ui-mockups

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Paper prototyping.  There's lots of information at [PaperPrototyping.com](http://www.paperprototyping.com).

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, you're wasting your time with enterprise tools, or charts and diagrams *in most cases*. Notepad will do. I learned it from a [friend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13502/tom-anderson), which he likes to use the term "Notepad Architecture", and frankly I have had *zero* problems with designing applications, the underworkings, how things flow with one another. All you need is a good design, not necessarily pretty pictures.

For example, when I developed my user based system, I would do the following in notepad:

```
User (Role Based) System
    - Administrators, Users
    - Sql Server 2008
    - Linq to Sql

        User (Abstract Base)
            - ID (GUID)
            - Alias
            - Username
            - Password (Encrypted, MD5 Hash)
            - First Name
            - Last Name
            - Email address
            - Account Type
                Administrator || User
```

Etcetera, etcetera. With the above as I type it, I already knew what and how it needed to be coded. What technologies were involved, and why they were involved. I didn't need any fancy drawing diagrams, or charts.

Ah, but what about complex events? Well, programming is like creative writing. Didn't you take a creative writing class before?

*The user will start the program executable. The first form to be displayed is the sign-in form. When the form is shown, the user will be prompted to enter their credentials. The user will enter their credentials, and click "Sign In". The Sign-In **service** will then check the credentials against the **database**. If the credentials match, the form will close and display the shell, otherwise will display an error and allow the user to try again.*

Now this is a small, but trivial and good example. Why on earth would I need a chart, flow chart, UML diagram, or other when all the logic and program flow is written elegantly (yes, feel free to critique) above? I know what needs to be written, again with what technologies, services, and how and what order to do it.

Trust me, notepad has been around for years! And there's a good reason for that, and why it hasn't changed any!

(It does take your mind a bit to get thinking a "creative writing" kind of way, but come on, you're a programmer! You do it everyday!

**edit:** [See this post also.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250127/telling-my-manager-that-having-a-plan-is-important/1250155#1250155)

Answer (score 0):

For me, fireworks is the best tool to design user interface. There are lots of tutorials of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

For the UI, look at

[Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/tour) or [iRise](http://irise.com/).

If you want to model the behavior behind the UI, look at [Enterprise Architect](http://sparxsystems.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ForeUI](http://www.foreui.com/), it is a tool for UI layout, interaction design and simulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mind-mapping tools to put down your ideas in an organized way. Though it may not help you model your UI, it helps keep your thoughts organized. You can try [Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). Its simple to learn and use.

Here's a sample from the Freemind wiki.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like good ol' paper and pencil. Also I recommend a book called [Effective Prototyping for Software Makers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120885689). Here is a link!